# Download if a file doesn't exist and send it using Flask

Tags: python-3.x, flask

Machine A (and it's a VM) is requesting a resource on machine B which is a Flask server.
If the file is not present on B, B request C(where the file is).
The question is: **how to transfer data back to A after B downloaded it?**

Here is my code:

```py
from flask import Flask, request, render_template
from pathlib import Path
from werkzeug import secure_filename    

import subprocess

app = Flask(__name__)
bashCommand="scp -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa ubuntu@machineC:/home/ubuntu/ostechnix.txt /home/adriano/"
file_content=""
@app.route('/', methods=['GET'])
def lora_frames_handler():
        if request.method == 'GET':
            print("Ca pop:")
            #received_json = request.get_json()
            #print(received_json)
        my_file = Path("/home/adriano/ostechnix.txt")
        if my_file.is_file():
            # file exists
            print("File present")
            file_content=""
        else:
            print("Not present")
            process = subprocess.Popen(bashCommand.split(), stdout=subprocess.PIPE) #with this I get the file on local
            output, error = process.communicate()
        with open("/home/adriano/ostechnix.txt") as f:
                file_content=f.read()    #This doesn't work
        return file_content
    
    if __name__ == '__main__':
        app.run(host="0.0.0.0", port=8080)
```

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try `flask.send_file`?

http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/api/#flask.send_file

Here's a proof of concept:

```py
from flask import Flask, jsonify, request, render_template, send_file
from pathlib import Path
import subprocess

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/')
def proxy_file():
    file_to_send = Path('/path/to/file')
    if not file_to_send.exists():
        # file does not exist
        fetch_file()

    # now we have the file
    return send_file(str(file_to_send))

def fetch_file():
    command = 'command to fetch the file'
    process = subprocess.Popen(command.split(), stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    output, error = process.communicate()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

If you need to stream the response from `scp` without saving it first (like when the file is too large, or you dont want the client to wait until file is downloaded), then you need a different approach, which I can clarify if you like.

Comment: The file is downloaded, but still not send back.
I changed my code like : https://pastebin.com/We0UK88X

Comment: What do you get when you visit `/` instead?

Comment: No, I meant when you run the server and visit `localhost:8081` in the browser, what do you see?

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/zhoHTsf, this mean curl, doesn't know how to handle the return?

Comment: Hmm. Does the file `ostechnix.txt` look ok when you open it manually?

Comment: It's a dummy file, I used truncate -s 5M ostechnix.txt,

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195976/discussion-between-abdusco-and-warok).